# The field is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed at Raven.Database.Indexing

Tags: c#, ravendb, hangfire

I am extremely new to RavenDB and HangFire and I'm creating a background task but I get an indexing error when I'm querying ravendb documents as shown below :

```
    public static void UpdateDoNotDisturb()
    {
        IList<HotelRoom> rooms = new List<HotelRoom>();
        Hotel project;
        IQueryable<HotelRoom> queryableObj;
        //Update Rooms with DND status and DndUntil greater than now.
        using (var session = MvcApplication.DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            queryableObj = session.Query<HotelRoom, HotelRoom_Search>().Where(x => x.Status == "DND" && x.DndUntilUtc < DateTime.Now).OfType<HotelRoom>();
            //queryableObj = session.Query<HotelRoom, HotelRoom_Search>().Where(x => x.Status == "DND").OfType<HotelRoom>();
            using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(queryableObj))
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var room = enumerator.Current.Document;
                    rooms.Add(room);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

on the document :

```
{
  "HotelId": "hotels/1474",
  "RoomNumber": "407",
  "Floor": "4th Floor",
  "Status": "DND",
  "RoomType": "Guest Room",
  "RoomTemplate": "1474_Install_SBBs.json",
  "Json": {
    "main": {
      "picRoomNumber": "Images/Photos/d5/d5de2652-08c3-49c7-a75a-446934962a1d.jpg",
      "qrCode": "http://2d.my/36tn"
    },
    "taskSBB1": {
      "deviceTvModelValue": "Other",
      "tvLocation": "None",
      "deviceTvModel": "Other",
      "itemSbbRemoved": 0,
      "deviceSbbQr": "http://2d.my/36tm",
      "deviceTvMountType": "Articulating wall mount",
      "deviceTvMountTypeValue": "Articulating wall mount",
      "tvLocationValue": "",
      "taskTechName": "Anton Anskin",
      "taskName": "Install SBB",
      "deviceTvSn": "703rmcj83595",
      "taskStatus": "In Progress",
      "deviceSbbPhotoMount": "Images/Photos/84/8410b77b-20f2-4146-b9cb-19e9dd3259ef.jpg",
      "taskStarted": "2017-06-06T14:50:34.046000Z"
    },
    "tasks": [
      "taskSBB1"
    ],
    "survey": {
      "sbbCount": "1",
      "damageBoolean": 0
    }
  },
  "LastUpdatedBy": "Mark",
  "LastUpdatedUtc": "2017-07-10T18:46:27.9305296Z",
  "StartedBy": null,
  "StartedUtc": "2017-06-06T14:50:34.0460000Z",
  "CompletedBy": null,
  "CompletedUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "CompletedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "DndBy": "Mark",
  "DndUntilUtc": "2017-07-10T21:46:00.0000000Z",
  "RoomPhotos": [
    {
      "Key": "main",
      "Name": "picRoomNumber",
      "ImagePath": "Images/Photos/d5/d5de2652-08c3-49c7-a75a-446934962a1d.jpg",
      "AddedBy": "Anton",
      "AddedUtc": "2017-06-06T14:51:16.6010049Z"
    },
    {
      "Key": "taskSBB1",
      "Name": "deviceSbbPhotoMount",
      "ImagePath": "Images/Photos/84/8410b77b-20f2-4146-b9cb-19e9dd3259ef.jpg",
      "AddedBy": "Anton",
      "AddedUtc": "2017-06-06T14:51:17.2572542Z"
    }
  ],
  "Issues": [],
  "Scans": [],
  "ChangeLog": [],
  "CurrentPhase": null
}
```

And I'm getting the error :

```
      "Error": "System.ArgumentException: The field 'DndUntilUtc' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed\r\n   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexed(IndexQuery indexQuery, AbstractViewGenerator viewGenerator)\r\n   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.<Query>d__57.MoveNext()\r\n   at Raven.Database.Util.ActiveEnumerable`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)\r\n   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass96.<Query>b__8b(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)\r\n   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext)\r\n   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)\r\n   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Query(String index, IndexQuery query, CancellationToken externalCancellationToken, Action`1 headerInfo, Action`1 onResult)\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.QueryStreams.Respond(IHttpContext context)\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx)\r\n   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx)"
    }

      Source=Raven.Client.Lightweight
      StackTrace:
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.RawExecuteRequest()
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.StreamQuery(String index, IndexQuery query, QueryHeaderInformation& queryHeaderInfo)
       at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Stream[T](IDocumentQuery`1 query, QueryHeaderInformation& queryHeaderInformation)
       at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Stream[T](IQueryable`1 query, QueryHeaderInformation& queryHeaderInformation)
       at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Stream[T](IQueryable`1 query)
```

I'm curious as to how to fix this error and why.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're querying the index 'HotelRoom_Search' with a property 'DndUntilUtc' but the index doesn't contain it.

In lucene/ravendb world, if you query the index by specific property [, although the collection (or table in sql world) contains it], it would work only if the index contains it. 
simply add the field 'DndUntilUtc' to your index.

your didn't included your index definition so i'll guess it's something like this :

```
public class HotelRoom_Search : AbstractIndexCreationTask<HotelRoom>
{
    public HotelRoom_Search()
    {
        Map = rooms => from room in rooms
                       select new
                       {
                           //bla bla
                           room.DndUntilUtc // add this line
                           //bla bla
                       };

        Indexes.Add(x => x.DndUntilUtc, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

    }
}
```

and don't forget to run this, so the server would be updated of the index definition :

```
var store = new DocumentStore { //....}
new HotelRoom_Search().Execute(Store);
```

UPDATE:

to overcome this you could also query the object HotelRoom without specifying the index (pass just the entity as T to session.Query). this would make ravendb create an Auto index according to the properties you use in your query.

ravendb docs:

> Indexes are used by server to satisfy queries, whenever a user issues a query RavenDB will use an existing index if it matches query or create a new one if no match is found.
>   Indexes created by issuing a query are calleddynamic or Auto indexes and can be easily identified, due to their name that starts withAuto/ prefix.
>   Indexes created explicitly by user are calledstatic.

usually you want to control the way raven indexes (and retrieves) docs to tune performance, so it's not a good option but good as default.

of course that wouldn't fix the bug.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed how and why.  Very definitive answer.

Comment: you're welcome. btw, I strongly recommend reading about lucene, because ravendb is based on lucene. try the book lucene in action, manners pub. and I'd appreciate if you accept it as answer.